# Kentico | Error on Upgrade - Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: kentico

After successfully upgrading from ver7 to ver8, can only see admin screens with actual site displaying below error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to
>   uniqueidentifier.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion
>   failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting from a
>   character string to uniqueidentifier.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +3189408
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +753
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +5042
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
>   +278    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more) +295
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() +42
>   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
>   +157    System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader,
>   Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn,
>   Object parentChapterValue) +225
>   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable,
>   IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords) +479
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +277
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +178
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +122
>   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText,
>   QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean
>   requiresTransaction) +251
>
> [Exception:  [DataConnection.HandleError]:
>
> Query:  SELECT   * FROM  (
>       SELECT   [PageID], [MenuItemName], [MenuItemTeaserImage], [Synopsis], [PermanentExhibition], [WheelchairAccessible], NULL AS
>   [HomeID], NULL AS [MenuItemGroup], ClassName, DocumentCulture,
>   DocumentGUID, DocumentModifiedWhen, DocumentMenuCaption,
>   DocumentMenuClass, DocumentMenuClassHighLighted,
>   DocumentMenuClassOver, DocumentShowInSiteMap,
>   DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation, DocumentMenuItemImage,
>   DocumentMenuItemImageHighlighted, DocumentMenuItemImageOver,
>   DocumentMenuItemInactive, DocumentMenuItemLeftImage,
>   DocumentMenuItemLeftImageHighlighted, DocumentMenuItemLeftImageOver,
>   DocumentMenuItemRightImage, DocumentMenuItemRightImageHighlighted,
>   DocumentMenuItemRightImageOver, DocumentMenuJavascript,
>   DocumentMenuRedirectUrl, DocumentMenuRedirectToFirstChild,
>   DocumentMenuStyle, DocumentMenuStyleHighlighted,
>   DocumentMenuStyleOver, DocumentName, DocumentUrlPath, NodeAliasPath,
>   NodeID, NodeChildNodesCount, NodeClassID, NodeLevel, NodeLinkedNodeID,
>   NodeParentID, SiteName, NodeACLID, NodeSiteID, NodeOwner, NodeOrder,
>   NodeName, DocumentSitemapSettings, NodeOrder AS CMS_O1, ROW_NUMBER()
>   OVER (ORDER BY DocumentName) AS CMS_SRN, 0 AS CMS_SN,
>   '**cms.document.nmi.page**' AS CMS_T FROM View_NMI_Page_Joined WHERE
>   NodeSiteID = @NodeSiteID AND (DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation = 0)
>   AND (Published = @Published AND NodeLevel <= @NodeLevel AND
>   DocumentCulture = @DocumentCulture) UNION ALL SELECT   NULL AS
>   [PageID], [MenuItemName], [MenuItemTeaserImage], NULL AS [Synopsis],
>   NULL AS [PermanentExhibition], NULL AS [WheelchairAccessible],
>   [HomeID], [MenuItemGroup], ClassName, DocumentCulture, DocumentGUID,
>   DocumentModifiedWhen, DocumentMenuCaption, DocumentMenuClass,
>   DocumentMenuClassHighLighted, DocumentMenuClassOver,
>   DocumentShowInSiteMap, DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation,
>   DocumentMenuItemImage, DocumentMenuItemImageHighlighted,
>   DocumentMenuItemImageOver, DocumentMenuItemInactive,
>   DocumentMenuItemLeftImage, DocumentMenuItemLeftImageHighlighted,
>   DocumentMenuItemLeftImageOver, DocumentMenuItemRightImage,
>   DocumentMenuItemRightImageHighlighted, DocumentMenuItemRightImageOver,
>   DocumentMenuJavascript, DocumentMenuRedirectUrl,
>   DocumentMenuRedirectToFirstChild, DocumentMenuStyle,
>   DocumentMenuStyleHighlighted, DocumentMenuStyleOver, DocumentName,
>   DocumentUrlPath, NodeAliasPath, NodeID, NodeChildNodesCount,
>   NodeClassID, NodeLevel, NodeLinkedNodeID, NodeParentID, SiteName,
>   NodeACLID, NodeSiteID, NodeOwner, NodeOrder, NodeName,
>   DocumentSitemapSettings, NodeOrder AS CMS_O1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER
>   BY DocumentName) AS CMS_SRN, 1 AS CMS_SN, '**cms.document.nmi.home**' AS
>   CMS_T FROM View_NMI_Home_Joined WHERE NodeSiteID = @NodeSiteID AND
>   (DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation = 0) AND (Published = @Published AND
>   NodeLevel <= @NodeLevel AND DocumentCulture = @DocumentCulture) )  AS
>   SubData ORDER BY CMS_O1, CMS_SRN, CMS_SN
>
> Caused exception:  Conversion failed when converting from a character
>   string to uniqueidentifier. ]
>   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.HandleError(String queryText,
>   Exception ex) +282
>   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText,
>   QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean
>   requiresTransaction) +342
>   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.RunQuery(QueryParameters query) +384 
>   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.ExecuteQueryInternal(QueryParameters
>   query) +458    CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDB() +149
>
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData() +120
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result() +106
>
>   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentQueryProperties.FilterResultsByPermissions(IDataQuery
>   query, Int32& totalRecords) +2128
>
>   CMS.DocumentEngine.MultiDocumentQueryBase`3.GetResults(IDataQuery
>   query, Int32& totalRecords) +54
>   CMS.DataEngine.MultiQueryBase`2.GetDataFromDB() +60
>
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData() +120
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result() +106
>   CMS.Controls.CMSAbstractMenuProperties.GetMenuItems(String
>   resolvedPath, Boolean siteMap) +910
>   CMS.Controls.CMSAbstractMenuProperties.GetDataSource(Boolean siteMap)
>   +839    CMS.Controls.CMSListMenu.ReloadData(Boolean forceLoad) +202    CMS.Controls.CMSListMenu.InitControl(Boolean loadPhase) +162
>   CMS.Controls.CMSListMenu.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +500
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +162
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3811
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0

I compared what I thought was the table giving the error with the Document Types  cms.document.nmi.home which inherits from cms.document.nmi.page and the conflicting data type 'MenuItemTeaserImage' and saw the following:

[image]

And the field type for the same data type in kentico admin is as follows:

https://snag.gy/ULS5Iz.jpg

How do I go about remedying this error? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Have you've made sure you've run the SQL scripts after the code upgrade (If you've done the upgrade manually)?

https://docs.kentico.com/k8/installation/upgrading-kentico-7-to-8/upgrading-kentico-manually

- Open the upgrade_8_0.sql script from the SQL directory in the upgrade installation folder.

---

Have you upgraded directly to Kentico 8.2? or is this the 8.0 version? If you do have you made sure the Site started between every upgrade? This will make sure all the DB updages are processed

Comment: I ran the upgrade initially with an error saying db wasn't upgraded so I ran script from the install folder you mentioned after again manually and it finished upgrade. I upgraded to v8.0 only and have ran site which gave above error. I have refactored a lot of custom code already (as after upgrade I turned on deployment mode in order to get access to page type 'CMS.Context' outdated code) but the above error is in relation to mismatching data types between a kentico field type (of a document type) and a db column data type?

Comment: Just to be sure I'd say replace the DB backup you've made before (right!) and do the complete upgrade manually to see if this results in the same issue.

Comment: Yes I have bak of both db and file structure pre upgrade. Do you recommend returning virtual files back to db (currently in file structure as deployment mode is on), restoring the version 7 db bak only and re running sql script in the version 8 install folder?

Comment: the virtual files represent your DB for some of the objects, so restoring a DB will result in different virtual files. So that should also be restored.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a custom page type **NMI_Page**, which had a **MenuItemTeaserImage** column. This column has exactly the same name as the MenuItemTeaserImage column in a different page type, but different type, which causes a conflict.

Using same field names in different page types is not recommended, so I used the page type name as a prefix for the field names.

I renamed the MenuItemTeaserImage field in the NMI_Page document type to **NMI_PageMenuItemTeaserImage** (and changed this name in all the transformations too).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the cause may have been a change in the **Page (menu item)** page type.  You're inheriting from this in you **NMI_Page** and perhaps the upgrade SQL did not deal with this effectively.  What you've done above clearly worked, but I'm curious if you could have broken the inheritance and fixed your teaser field?

Comment: I double checked that but it was NMI_Home that was inheriting from NMI_Page so renaming the field in the NMI_Page page type couldn't break the inheritance from the parent field, as this page type is not inheriting from any other page type.